# CustomShadowVariables and ScoreDirector

Tags: optaplanner

I have a custom shadow variable that is supposed to update a list of assignments for a person as they're assigned to jobs.  This is to enable a rule that, e.g. a Person can only have x shifts per week.  I figure maintaining this list of shifts per person as we go in a shadow variable should be easier than trying to calculate it in the solver rules.

When I run the solver, on the first iteration, the Solver crashes with this exception:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The
>   entity (Black) was never added to this ScoreDirector. Usually the
>   cause is that that specific instance was not in your Solution's
>   entities.

I'm not entirely sure what this means. The entity Black is an instance of a planning entity which is both annotated and defined in the config.xml, and it's in the set of problem facts.

My shadow variable is defined as:

```
@CustomShadowVariable(
        variableListenerClass = PersonAssignmentListener.class,
        sources = {@CustomShadowVariable.Source(
                variableName = "startingTimeGrain",
                entityClass = Assignment.class)
        }
)
public List<Assignment> getAssignments() {
    return assignments;
}
```

The listener for the shadow variable looks like this:

```
@Override
public void afterEntityAdded(ScoreDirector scoreDirector, 
                             Assignment assignment) {
    updatePerson(scoreDirector, assignment);
}

@Override
public void afterVariableChanged(ScoreDirector scoreDirector,
                             Assignment assignment) {
    updatePerson(scoreDirector, assignment);
}

private void updatePerson(ScoreDirector scoreDirector,
                          Assignment sourceAssignment) {

    Shift shift = sourceAssignment.getShift();
    Person p = sourceAssignment.getPerson();

    scoreDirector.beforeVariableChanged(away, "assignments");
    p.getAssignments().add(sourceAssignment);
    scoreDirector.afterVariableChanged(away, "assignments");
}
```

The exception occurs on the "afterVariableChanged" call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's unrelated to the chained or shadow vars.

Check the methods on your PlanningSolution class that have a EntityCollectionProperty annotation. That instance Black won't be in there.

Comment: Error message improved for OptaPlanner 7.0.0.Beta1

Comment: Thanks, turns out that particular variable didn't need to be a PlanningEntity in the first place.